# mysql query to fetch film and its song from two table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using following code to fetch film and song from two films and songs table
the issue is I can fetch only on song of that film using below query.
but my requirement is to fetch all the songs of that film from song table which is having same filmid for its song.

```
$url=$_GET['url'];   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM films f    
inner join songs s on f.filmId = s.filmId    
WHERE f.url='$url'";
```

I also need to combine `DATE_FORMAT(filmReleaseDate, '%d %M %Y' )` filmReleaseDate in above code

**Table Structure**

**Film table**

```
`filmId`,`filmName`,`url`,`director`,`actor`
```

**Song table**

```
`songId`,`songName`,`filmId`,`filmName`
```

Comment: What is your Schema Detail ?

Comment: show your `films` and `songs` DB table structure

Comment: This will fetch all films under that URL which have at least one song, and ALL said songs! Perhaps your problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: i have provided the table structure above in main question

Comment: sql injection, anyone?

Comment: run that query in phpmyadmin or some mysql tools if error occurs show that. I think error not in your query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url=$_GET['url'];   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM films f    
left join songs s on f.filmId = s.filmId    
WHERE f.url='$url'";
```